# C# Vimeo Upload - not working

Tags: c#, vimeo-api

I'm trying to upload a video to my professional account in Vimeo using Vimeo documantation at : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#upload-your-video

Just to try it I've made a simple C# console app :
I can get the upload_ticket.

When I "PUT" the video using WebClient.UploadData the file is sent.

```
try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers.Clear();
            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer xxxxxxxxxxx");
            wc.Headers.Add("type", "streaming");                

            var vimeoTicket = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(wc.UploadString("https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos", "POST", ""));

            var file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\3.mp4");

            wc.Headers.Clear();                

            var result= wc.UploadData(new Uri(vimeoTicket["upload_link_secure"].ToString()), "PUT", file);              

            WebClient wc1 = new WebClient();
            wc1.Headers.Clear();
            wc1.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "bytes */*");

            //This line will get me an execption {"The remote server returned an error: (308) Resume Incomplete."}
            var ff1 = wc1.UploadData(vimeoTicket["upload_link_secure"].ToString(), "PUT", new byte[0]);                
        }
        catch (Exception h)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

in the API doc it says "If this file exists, this will return a response with a HTTP 308 status code and a Range header with the number of bytes on the server."

So why I get an exception without and I dont get any response as in the doc??

Thank you

Comment: What type of exception do you receive?
EDIT: Sorry, didn't see it in your code: `//This line will get me an execption {"The remote server returned an error: (308) Resume Incomplete."}`

Comment: I'd try using wireshark and hope to see what really happens over the wire. Also, perhaps catching the exception and inspecting the inner exception (if any) may give you some ideas.

Comment: Tried to use the first approach in vimeo upload api -> simple "POST" that one is working, but no resume and no progress bar

Comment: Hey, i'm trying to figure how to do resumable uploads in C#, was wondering why are you uploading it twice - once with "file", and second time with "new byte[0]"? thanks

Comment: Vimeo has a new APi so.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the WebClient handle response 308 as an error, for now I've managed to put the code I need into the exception block - until I'll find a way to convince WebClinet 308 is not an enemy....

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string SaveVideoToVimeo(string fileName, long size, string caption, string description)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        try
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/upload/question/files"), fileName + ".webm");

            string vVimeURL = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.Headers.Clear();
            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4");
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string vData = "{\"upload\": {" + "\"approach\":\"tus\"," + "\"size\":\"" + size + "\" }, \"name\": \"" + caption + "\", \"description\":\"" + description + "\"}";
            var result = wc.UploadString(vVimeURL, "POST", vData);

            var vimeoTicket = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(result,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
            var LocationLink = vimeoTicket["upload"];
            var link = vimeoTicket["link"];

            string xx = vimeoTicket["uri"].ToString();
            wc.Headers.Clear();
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/offset+octet-stream");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4");
            wc.Headers.Add("Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0");
            wc.Headers.Add("Upload-Offset", "0");

            string vupload_link = LocationLink["upload_link"].ToString(); ;
            byte[] vResponse = wc.UploadFile(vupload_link, "PATCH", path);

            var returndata = new { code = 0, message = "Kayıt Başarıyla Yüklendi", style = "success", link = link };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returndata, Formatting.Indented);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var returndata = new { code = ex.HResult, message = ex.Message, style = "error", link = "" };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returndata, Formatting.Indented);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**